# Cannot access files within subdomains or folders

Tags: http-status-code-404, subdomain, bluehost

I created a sub domain named test on http://www.t2transfer.com/ and I put a index file. When I go to http://www.t2transfer.com/test/ url It shows a 404 page and blue host webpage. I also tried by creating a folder names test. But It also shows same result. Why is that? Please guide me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing a folder path, a sub-domain would look like http://test.t2transfer.com/

Comment: like that way also cannot access the sub domain.If create a folder, It also cannot access.404 error occur.

Comment: So you might need to check to see if there is something causing a 404, such as a special .htaccess, web.config, or some other type of web configuration file.

Comment: Thank you. I found some special rewrite modules in my .htaccess file. When I comment all that it solved.